# When I am pass the array as arguments then I am faceing this error invalid types 'int[int]' in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, function-declaration

I am new to c++. can anyone guide me on how I can pass the array in functions?

basically, I am trying to find a number with a linear search and print the index of that number in c++

```
   // linear search 
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int search(int arr, int n, int x)
    {
        int i=0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (arr[i] == x){
                return i;}
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Driver code
    int main(void)
    {
        int size;
        int temp;
        cout << "Enter Size of Arry";
        cin >> size;
        int  arr[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            cout << "Enter a " << i << "Element of your arry : ";
            cin >> temp;
            arr[i]=temp;
    
        }
        
    
         cout << "Enter the number that you will find index";
            int x;
         cin >> x;
        // Function call
        int result = search(arr, size, x);
        (result == -1)
            ? cout << "Element is not present in array"
            : cout << "Element is present at index " << result;
        return 0;
    }
```

this is the error

```
Q1.cpp: In function 'int search(int, int, int)':
Q1.cpp:9:12: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
   if (arr[i] == x){
            ^
Q1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Q1.cpp:35:34: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
  int result = search(arr, size, x);
                                  ^
```

Comment: `arr` is not an array in your `int search(int arr, int n, int x)` instead its a single integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters variable length arrays like this

```
int  arr[size];
```

is not a standard C++ feature. Instead it would be much better to use the standard container `std::vector<int>` in a C++ program.

Secondly the function declaration is incorrect. The first parameter is declared as having the type int.

```
int search(int arr, int n, int x)
```

You need to declare the function the following way

```
int search(int arr[], int n, int x)
```

or equivalently

```
int search(int *arr, int n, int x)
```

Pay attention to that there is standard algorithm `std::find` in C++ that performs searching an element in a container.

Answer (score 1):

**First** in C++, the size of an array must be a **compile-time constant**.So,  take for example the following code snippets:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //INCORRECT because n is not a constant expression
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //CORRECT
```

Similarly, the following(which you did in your code example) is incorrect:

```
    int size;
    int temp;
    cout << "Enter Size of Arry";
    cin >> size;
    int  arr[size];//INCORRECT because variable size is not a constant  expression
```

You should use `std::vector` for your purpose as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
//the first argument is a vector<int>
int search(std::vector<int> arr, int x)
{
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){//use size()member function
        if (arr[i] == x){
            return i;}
    }
    return -1;
}

// Driver code
int main(void)
{
    int size;
    int temp;
    cout << "Enter Size of Arry";
    cin >> size;
    //create a vector instead of an array 
    std::vector<int> arr(size);
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){//use the size member function
        cout << "Enter a " << i << "Element of your arry : ";
        cin >> temp;
        arr[i]=temp;

    }
    

     cout << "Enter the number that you will find index";
        int x;
     cin >> x;
    // Function call
    int result = search(arr,  x);//no need to pass the size of the vector
    (result == -1)
        ? cout << "Element is not present in array"
        : cout << "Element is present at index " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can also use `std::find` instead of writing your own search algorithm.

Comment: thanks, brother that help a lot but after a compilation, of my program, close, can you explain to me why it should happen

Comment: @TalhaIqbal You're welcome. Can you pinpoint at which point(line) of the program you have further doubts. It was not clear from your last comment what exactly are you asking . Can you clarify what further doubts(if any) you have.

Comment: `int search(std::vector<int> arr, int x)` the variable `arr` probably should be passed by const reference.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes ideally it should be passed as reference to const. But i just wanted to give a demo about how `vector` can be used/passed instead of an array and didn't want him to get confused(in case he was not already aware of  references). Also since you're nitpicking i will do the same. Technically, there are **no** `const reference`s in C++. The more technically correct term is a reference to const.